pyInstaller making huge exe file
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

All I did was import these three modules from Flask, and my executable file ended up being 319 MB. I'm using Conda and have a lot of modules installed.
The command that I use: pyinstaller --onefile myFile.py
I asked my friend, who has the same environment and also works with Conda. Our .spec file has the same configurations, and his executable file for my code was only 9 MB. I can't submit such a big file and have no idea why my PyInstaller includes modules such as Matplotlib, etc.

Hi there, @Noamk. And welcome to SOF. In such scenarios always bring what you have done code/command wise. This is a bit broad. Also, flask brings alongside many dependencies. However, if your file has literally, only those imports and nothing else it should be at 8 MB. By running du name_of_file.py. On my mac 8 MB, in Kali, 4 MB. So elaborate more on the question, by bringing prints and other important info related to the issue. For that is some weird behaviour.

Sorry for the misinformation. As I mentioned in the post, I only imported from flask import Flask, request, jsonify. I tried the command pyinstaller --onefile myFile.py in the PyCharm terminal. I use Conda, which has at least 70-100 modules in it. After that, I used a Python interpreter (3.10) that has 10-15 modules and got a 7MB executable file. For now, I will just use that file and change the interpreter when I need to convert.

Always create a virtual environment (venv) which only contains the modules you really need. That's the key to keeping pyinstaller files small.
This is how you would do it:
# create virtual environment
python -m venv my_env
# activate the virtual environment
my_env/bin/activate
# install your dependencies into your virtual environment
python -m pip install pyinstaller flask
# run pyinstaller inside your virtual environment
pyinstaller --onefile myFile.py

The resulting file should be around 8-9 MB.

After creating the virtual environment, will the executable file stand alone? I need to submit the executable for automated testing, which requires Python 3.10 but no other modules.

Yes it will. Pyinstaller still works as expected, meaning you get a standalone executable. A virtual environment uses the same python version that was used to create it. And after creating the executable you should also test it yourself to make sure it works as expected.
